# How to fix files being deleted when running function to change name

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import glob, os
def rename_files(string):
   os.chdir("files")
   num = 1
   for file in glob.glob('*'):
      os.rename(file, '{0}_{1}'.format(string, num))
      print(num)
      num = num + 1
   print("Renaming Successful...")
rename_files("TextFile")
```

If I have a directory that holds 10 files named foo1 - foo10 when I call this function I expect the files to be renamed TextFile1 - TextFile10.

Usually, this will work but if I run the program again it will delete some of the files. if I add new files to the directory and then I run the program more files will be deleted.

I don't know what is causing this problem and would really appreciate some help figuring it out. for example:

Starting directory: 
foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8, foo9, foo10

Directory after the first pass through the function:
TextFile_1 ... TextFile_10

Directory after the second pass through the function:
TextFile_3, TextFile_4, TextFile_5, TextFile_7, TextFile_9, TextFile_10

If I pass I run it one more time it will order the directory from TextFile_1 ... TextFile_6

Why is this happening?

Comment: maybe you need os.walk as an iterator to traverse all of the files in your folder:'files'

Comment: Beside the point, but it's cleaner to use `enumerate` for numbering things, like `for num, file in enumerate(glob.glob('*'), 1):`

Answer (score 2):

Files are not deleted, but overwritten.

If you start with two files `file1` and `file2` and then rename `file1` -> `file2`, then you end up with only one file (named `file2` but containing data from former `file1`).

The correct logic is to check if the destination name is already taken, e.g.:

```
while True:
    newname = '{0}_{1}'.format(string, num)
    num += 1
    if not os.path.exists(newname):
        break
os.rename(file, newname)
```

There is still a small problem, so called race condition. But it only matters if two programs are renaming the files in the same directory simultaneously.